# Is it Possible to Make a Simple C# Marquee Progress Bar without a Background Worker?

Tags: c#, .net, progress-bar

I have a very simple form with a progress bar on it and a delete button.  When the user clicks "Delete", a stored procedure runs for around five minutes.

I would like a simple marquee progress bar to run but it never appears. I read all the other questions about this but they all required a background worker.

Is it possible to make a marquee progress bar without a background worker?

```
    public partial class ProgressBarSample
{
    public ProgressBarSample

        {
            progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            progressBar1.Visible = false;
        }


    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            // run stored procedure that takes around 5 minutes
            Task.Delay(10000);
            progressBar1.Visible = false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
progressBar1.Visible = true;
// run stored procedure that takes around 5 minutes
Task.Delay(10000);
progressBar1.Visible = false;
```

prevents windows messages from being processed by your application until the delay completes because you block the thread responsible for processing those messages. Windows relies on those messages being processed in a timely manner.

The result is that your user interface will appear unresponsive to the user.

There are a number of mechanisms that allow you to do your processing on a second thread. BackgroundWorker is one that was commonly used at the time WinForms first came out and still a solid choice. You can use any technique that does the long-running work on another thread, but you must do it on that other thread.

You can use the async pattern to simplify the coding for that other thread

```
private async void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // run stored procedure that takes around 5 minutes
        Task.Delay(10000);
    });
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: The code you are commenting on does not do what you say it is, because the `Task.Delay()` method doesn't block. Now, if the OP has posted a bad question, in which they provide code that doesn't actually reproduce the specific problem they are having, and in fact they have something that _does_ block in the place of where they are currently showing `Task.Delay()`, then your suggestion would be more appropriate. But then you're answering a different question than was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem, it's impossible to say for sure what the issue is. However, the code you posted won't work. Your `btnDelete_Click()` method sets the `Visible` property to `true`, but then immediately sets it back to `false`, because the `Task.Delay()` method doesn't actually block.

Probably what you want is this:

```
private async void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
    // run stored procedure that takes around 5 minutes
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: The code sample seems to be sufficient to understand the issue. A complete (compilable) WinForms sample has a lot of baggage that would detract from the core issue. He inserted Task.Delay as a proxy for a call to a stored procedure in his real code so Task.Delay isn't exactly what he's after.

Comment: @EricJ.: inserting a non-blocking call as a proxy for a blocking call, while plausible, is _wrong_ and prevents anyone from actually knowing what the code does. The OP needs to provide a good [mcve] if they want an answer that actually addresses their question.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWorker is the generally accepted method for doing such background work, hence the name; but for a primitive "show for X period of time", you could use a Timer that checks the amount of time passed since (in this case) delete was last clicked to see if it should hide the control (and disable itself, no use ticking when there is nothing to do.)

Something like:

```
public partial class ProgressBarSample
{
    TimeSpan pbShowDuration = [blah blah];
    DateTime pbShowFrom = DateTime.MinDate;

    public ProgressBarSample
    {
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        pbShowFrom = DateTime.Now;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        // run stored procedure that takes around 5 minutes
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now - pbShowFrom) > pbShowDuration)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            progressBar1.Visible = false;           
        }
    }
}
```

But how are you planning to update the progress bar?

Comment: The run time of a stored procedure isn't very predictable. It might complete in 2 minutes on a QA server with less data or in 10 minutes if the server is under heavy load or if the server has more data at some point in the future. Inserting a proper time for `[blah blah]` is nearly impossible.

Comment: @EricJ. Just going by what was included in the question, and why I prefaced the example with the description of "primitive 'show for X period of time'". Obviously the ideal solution would be backgroundworker or some other form of threading; most tasks that need a progress bar aren't highly predictable (not just stored procs), even loading a file will vary significantly if other processes are taxing the storage medium/bandwidth enough.

Comment: @Uueerdo - the marquee just goes in a circle which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

With the new task, sync, await features in C# you have a lot of options. If you don't need to do anything other than let the user know the operation is done you can start your progress bar, then start a task that runs your proc and when it's done stop the progress bar. I would personally put something other than a progress bar. To me a progress bar means you have a finite amount of time to wait. If your SP can vary in time I would go with some kind of busy display icon or something like that.

I personally would useh Task.ContinueWith in this case.

This MSDN article show a great way to handle it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Background worker is an old method which is superseded by using Tasks. Tasks have more functionality, can do things backgroundworkers cannot, and are much simpler to use.